# PropTypes.oneOfType not working as I expect with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-proptypes

I want to allow a component to have one of different possible actions. I am using `PropTypes.oneOfType` to do this.

When I use `PropTypes.inferTypes` to deduce types in TypeScript I get a compilation error.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes, { InferProps } from "prop-types";

const Action1 = PropTypes.shape({
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(["action1"]).isRequired,
  string1: PropTypes.string.isRequired
});

const Action2 = PropTypes.shape({
  type: PropTypes.oneOf(["action2"]).isRequired,
  string1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  string2: PropTypes.string.isRequired
});

const ActionType = {
  action: PropTypes.oneOfType([Action1, Action2])
};

export const ActionComponent = (
  props: InferProps<typeof ActionType>
): JSX.Element => {
  return <p>{props}</p>;
};

ActionComponent.propTypes = ActionType;

const a = <ActionComponent action={{ type: "action1", string1: "bye" }} />;  // ok
const b = (
  <ActionComponent
    action={{ type: "action2", string1: "bye", string2: "test" }}  // string2 not ok
  />
);
```

The error I get is

```
Type '{ type: string; string1: string; string2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InferProps<{ type: Validator<string>; string1: Validator<string>; }>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'string2' does not exist in type 'InferProps<{ type: Validator<string>; string1: Validator<string>; }>'. Did you mean to write 'string1'?  TS2322
```

This may be a simple mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Interestingly this seems to happen only if the actions have more than one property name in common: `type` and `string1` in this example.

Comment: If you are using TypeScript, there is actually no need for `propTypes`.

Comment: Indeed, just declare plain Typescript interfaces, use the ? symbol for optional fields and use it with React.FC, eg: `const Component: React.FC<{title: string}> = ({title}) => <>{title}</>`

Comment: I know that you can just use TypeScript interfaces, but we want to be able to know the property types of components at runtime. Also to support JavaScript components if necessary. And this proptypes -> typescript derivation is what `InferProps` is there for.